# Mysql return where sum of values is less than value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I've a situation where I need to retrieve ALL products WHERE `Alert` is TRUE, the `MininumAlert` value is < of the sum of qnty of product in each store and StoreDetail.Search = 1. For example:

table Product:

```
-------------------------------------
| ID | Name  | MinimumAlert | Alert |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | Prod1 |   100        |   1   |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | Prod2 |   150        |   1   |
-------------------------------------
| 3  | Prod3 |   500        |   1   |
-------------------------------------
| 4  | Prod4 |              |   0   |
-------------------------------------
| 5  | Prod5 |   110        |   1   |
```

table StoreDetail:

```
------------------------------
| ID | Name  | Search       | 
-----------------------------
| 100  | Store1|   1          |   
------------------------------
| 101  | Store2|   1          |  
------------------------------
| 102  | Store3|   1          |  
-----------------------------
| 103  | Store4|   1          |  
------------------------------
| 104  | Store5|   1          |
```

table Store:

```
-------------------------------------
| ID | Store_ID| Qty          | Prod_ID|
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 100     |   5          |   1   |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | 101     |   90         |   1   |
-------------------------------------
| 4  | 100     |   400        |   2   |
-------------------------------------
| 5  | 101     |   30         |   2   |
-------------------------------------
| 6  | 100     |   450         |   3   |
 -------------------------------------
| 7  | 100     |   99         |   4   |
 -------------------------------------
| 8  | 100     |   98         |   5   |
 -------------------------------------
| 9  | 101     |   2          |   5   |
-------------------------------------
| 10  | 102     |   3          |   5   |
```

I don't know hot to retrieve IDs from (Product table) in ONE QUERY.
I actually use a function in PHP like this (using 2 queries: 1 inside `get_all_products` func and another 1 inside `get_stores_by_prod_ID` func):

```
function get_products_under_minimum() {

   $result = array();

   $all_products = get_all_products(); //SELECT * FROM Product

   foreach ( $all_products as $product ) {
     if ( $product['Alert'] ) {
       $total = 0;
       $all_stores_product = get_stores_by_prod_ID( $product['ID'] ); // SELECT * FROM Store WHERE Prod_ID = $product['ID']
       foreach ( $all_stores_product as $store) {
           $info_store = get_info_store($store['Store_ID']); // SELECT * FROM StoreDetail WHERE ID = ?
           if ( $info_store['Search'] ) {
            $total = $total + $store['Qty'];
           }
       }

       if ( $total < $product['MinimumAlert'] ) {
          $result[] = $product['ID'];
       }

     }
   }

   return $result;

}
```

Based on my rules, I need to retrieve:

```
ID 1 cause Alert is true, Search is true and SUM(5+90) is < 100
ID 3 cause Alert is true, Search is true and SUM(450) is < 500
ID 5 cause Alert is true, Search is true and SUM(98+2+3) is < 110
```

I'd like, if possible, to use only a single QUERY to

Comment: I think you can do this with one query using `having` and `group by`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN` between the tables using their appropriate relationships. We can then `GROUP BY` on the product ID, Name, and MinimumAlert (to be compatible with only_full_group_by mode).

We can then use `SUM()` function to calculate the total `Qty` from all the stores, and use `HAVING` clause to consider those products where `MinimumAlert` is more than the total store quantity.

```sql
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.MinimumAlert, 
       SUM(s.Qty) AS total_store_qty 
FROM product p
JOIN store s ON s.Prod_ID = p.ID 
JOIN storedetail sd ON sd.ID = s.Store_ID 
WHERE p.alert = 1 AND 
      sd.search = 1 
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Name, p.MinimumAlert
HAVING p.MinimumAlert > total_store_qty
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've forgot another table, sorry. I've added now: StoreDetail. I need to filter also by Search = true.

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini you can simply add one more JOIN condition